# Trouble Finding The Segmentation Fault Cause(s)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++

The code keeps giving segmentation fault ( core dropped ) error

I have feel like something is wrong with the getNumberParticles() ; as when i just have return 0 as the function definition there is no error but if i return anything else but 0 theres an error

also if you will tell me to use gdb 
its a multiple file program with one main
im not sure how to debug it like that

particleList.cpp

```
    ParticleList::ParticleList() {
    numParticles = 0;
    particles[500] = {};
    }

//  ParticleList::ParticleList(int rows, int cols){
//  numParticles = 0;
//  particles[rows * cols * 4] = {};
//  } 

    ParticleList::ParticleList(const ParticleList& obj){

    }
    // Clean-up the particle list
    ParticleList::~ParticleList() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++){
            delete particles[i];
    }
    }

    // Number of particles in the ParticleList
    int ParticleList::getNumberParticles() {
        numParticles = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++){

            if(particles[i] != nullptr){
                numParticles++;
            }
     }
       return this->numParticles;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the i-th particle in the list
    ParticlePtr ParticleList::get(int i) {
       return particles[i-1];
    }

    // Add a particle (as a pointer) to the list
    //    This class now has control over the pointer
    //    And should delete the pointer if the particle is removed from the list
    void ParticleList::add_back(ParticlePtr particle) {
        int quantity = getNumberParticles();
        particles[quantity]= particle;
    }

    // Remove all particles from the list
    void ParticleList::clear() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++){
            particles[i]= nullptr;
        }
    }
```

ParticleList.h

```
#ifndef COSC_ASS_ONE_PARTICLE_LIST
#define COSC_ASS_ONE_PARTICLE_LIST

#include "Particle.h"
#include "Types.h"

class ParticleList {
public:

   /*                                           */
   /* DO NOT MOFIFY ANY CODE IN THIS SECTION    */
   /*                                           */


   // Create a New Empty List
   ParticleList();

   ParticleList(const ParticleList& obj); //Copy Construcor

   // Clean-up the particle list
   ~ParticleList();

   // Number of particles in the ParticleList
   int getNumberParticles();

   // Get a pointer to the i-th particle in the list
   ParticlePtr get(int i);

   // Add a particle (as a pointer) to the list
   //    This class now has control over the pointer
   //    And should delete the pointer if the particle is removed from the list
   void add_back(ParticlePtr particle);

   // Remove all particles from the list
   // Don't forget to clean-up the memory!
   void clear();

   /*                                           */
   /* YOU MAY ADD YOUR MODIFICATIONS HERE       */
   /*                                           */
   ParticleList(int rows, int cols);
   /* This is a suggestion of what you could use. */
   /* You can change this code.                   */
private:

    // particle* particles[300] 
    //Array of pointers to particle objects
   ParticlePtr    particles[500];
   int           numParticles;



};
```

Comment: First of all, this would be a perfect opportunity for you to [learn](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) about debuggers and how to use them to find such bugs.

Comment: Your `getNumberParticle` looks fine, but your `get` subtracts by one, so I guess you have some off-by-one error somewhere.

Comment: first of all , in your constructor, particles[500] is out of bound of your array. And if you want to set it to null, use memset.

Comment: In your constructor, you set `particles[500] = {}`, but `particles` only goes from 0 to 499.

Comment: `particles[500] = {};` does not zero-initialise your array; it's an assignment and, because of a syntactic quirk, it's equivalent to `particles[500] = 0;`.

Comment: So how do we debug , on the note there are multiple cpp files with one main which complile together

Comment: The reason why I did particles[500]={} in constructor is because it's not initialised or is it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your class:

1. I don't see anything it provides that `std::vector<ParticlePtr>` doesn't also provide (correctly).
2. You have not provided assignment operator, and thus violated the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).
3. Your copy constructor is incorrect, and doesn't initialize any of your members.
4. Your `get` method implements 1-based indexing, which is very likely to confuse everybody.

It is very likely that issue 2 or 3 above is the root cause of your crash.

But issue 1 should be enough to throw away this code and replace it with `std::vector`.

Comment: oh , we arent allowed to use STL stuff like vectors